# Temp table -inner join

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I wrote this query to inner join the temp table with another SQL table:

```
(SELECT 
id FROM
  #Temp WHERE code<>10
)AS s inner join table1 r on s.id=r.id)
```

I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: For starters you have one opening bracket and two closing brackets which is not valid in _any_ language. Post the whole query please, and it would also help to post the database platform. Maybe we need to burninate the SQL tag

Answer (score 0):

The only sense I can make of your code is a query like this:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM #Temp s JOIN
     table1 r 
     ON s.id = r.id
WHERE s.code <> 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select s.id, r.* 
from
(SELECT id 
 FROM #Temp 
 WHERE code<>10
) s 
inner join table1 r on s.id=r.id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.